# Sorting files in sharepoint folder (2007)

Tags: sharepoint

I am looking for a way to sort files by date (id seems to do the same).

SPFolder imageFolder = web.GetFolder(...);
...

I know I have to do this with caml but how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be done with a CAML query. Use the [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) class to execute such a query. Use the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467378.aspx) element in order to sort the result set:

```
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="yourdatefield" />
</OrderBy>
```

Example:

```
SPList list = ... // the list where you images are stored.

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = imageFolder;
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" /></OrderBy>";

SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

The variable `items` now contains the contents of the `imageFolder` sorted by the field "Created".

In order to access the image files use the member `File` on `SPListItem`:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + item.File.Name);
}
```

Comment: SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();

oQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRefAscending = 'False' Name ='id' /></OrderBy>";

But how do I use the query to get files? I used: imageFolder.Files
but it accepts no arguments.